# Differences in the values plots in strategy and study

Tags: pine-script

I'm turning the strategy into a study. [Noro's RiskDonchian Strategy](https://www.tradingview.com/script/JHBIDlp8-noro-s-riskdonchian-strategy/)

My current script

```
//@version=4
//strategy(title = "Noro's RiskDonchian Indicator", shorttitle = "RiskDonchian indi", overlay = true, default_qty_type = strategy.percent_of_equity, initial_capital = 100, default_qty_value = 100, commission_value = 0.1)
study(title = "Noro's RiskDonchian Indicator", shorttitle = "RiskDonchian indi", overlay = true)

//Settings
needlong = input(true, title = "Long")
needshort = input(true, title = "Short")
tp = input(3.0, minval = 1, title = "Take-profit, %")
tptype = input(defval = "2. Fix", options = ["1. None", "2. Fix", "3. Trailing"], title = "Take-profit type")
sltype = input(defval = "2. Center", options = ["1. None", "2. Center"], title = "Take-profit type")
risklong  = input(1.0, minval = 0.0, maxval = 99.9, title = "Risk size for long, %")
riskshort = input(1.0, minval = 0.0, maxval = 99.9, title = "Risk size for short, %")
pclen = input(20, minval = 1, title = "Price Channel Length")
showll = input(true, title = "Show lines")
showbg = input(false, title = "Show Background")
showof = input(false, title = "Show Offset")
showlabel = input(true, title = "Show label")
fromyear = input(1900, minval = 1900, maxval = 2100, title = "From Year")
toyear = input(2100, minval = 1900, maxval = 2100, title = "To Year")
frommonth = input(01, minval = 01, maxval = 12, title = "From Month")
tomonth = input(12, minval = 01, maxval = 12, title = "To Month")
fromday = input(01, minval = 01, maxval = 31, title = "From day")
today = input(31, minval = 01, maxval = 31, title = "To day")

var  position = 0 // analogue strategy.position_size

//Price Channel
h = highest(high, pclen)
l = lowest(low, pclen)
center = (h + l) / 2

//Take-profit
tpl = 0.0
tpl := tptype == "2. Fix" and position > 0 ? tpl[1] : h * (100 + tp) / 100

//Stop-loss
tps = 0.0
tps := tptype == "2. Fix" and position < 0 ? tps[1] : l * (100 - tp) / 100

//Lines
tplcol = showll and needlong and tptype != "1. None" ? color.lime : na
pclcol = showll and needlong ? color.blue : na
sllcol = showll and needlong and sltype != "1. None" ? color.red : na
tpscol = showll and needshort and tptype != "1. None" ? color.lime : na
pcscol = showll and needshort ? color.blue : na
slscol = showll and needshort and sltype != "1. None" ? color.red : na
offset = showof ? 1 : 0
plot(tpl, offset = offset, color = tplcol, title = "TP Long")
plot(h, offset = offset, color = pclcol, title = "Channel High")
plot(center, offset = offset, color = sllcol, title = "SL Long")
plot(center, offset = offset, color = slscol, title = "SL Short")
plot(l, offset = offset, color = pcscol, title = "Channel Low")
plot(tps, offset = offset, color = tpscol, title = "TP Short")

//Background
size = position
bgcol = showbg == false ? na : size > 0 ? color.lime : size < 0 ? color.red : na
bgcolor(bgcol, transp = 70)

//Lot size
// risksizelong = -1 * risklong
// risklonga = ((center / h) - 1) * 100
// coeflong = abs(risksizelong / risklonga)
// lotlong = (strategy.equity / close) * coeflong
// risksizeshort = -1 * riskshort
// riskshorta = ((center / l) - 1) * 100
// coefshort = abs(risksizeshort / riskshorta)
// lotshort = (strategy.equity / close) * coefshort

//Trading
truetime = time > timestamp(fromyear, frommonth, fromday, 00, 00) and time < timestamp(toyear, tomonth, today, 23, 59)
mo = 0
mo := position != 0 ? 0 : high >= center[1] and low <= center[1] ? 1 : mo[1]

if h > 0 and position[1] == 0 and needlong and truetime and high >= h[1]
    position := 1

if position[1] == 1 and needlong and truetime and (high >= tpl[1] or low <= center[1])
    position := 0

if h > 0 and position[1] == 0 and needshort and truetime and low <= l[1]
    position := -1

if position[1] == -1 and needshort and truetime and (low <= tps[1] or high >= center[1])
    position := 0

plotshape(position[1] == 0 and position[0] == 1, style=shape.triangleup, color=color.green, location=location.belowbar, text="Long", size=size.tiny)
plotshape(position[1] == 1 and position[0] == 0, style=shape.xcross, color=color.green, text="Exit Long", size=size.tiny)

plotshape(position[1] == 0 and position[0] == -1, style=shape.triangledown, color=color.red, text="Short", size=size.tiny)
plotshape(position[1] == -1 and position[0] == 0, style=shape.xcross, color=color.red, location=location.belowbar, text="Exit Short", size=size.tiny)
```

After the conversion, there were differences in the formation of channels. Differences arise when there is an open position in the strategy. The screenshot shows that the lime color channels do not match, and the blue color channels do not match, only they have minor differences.
[image]
What could be the reason for such differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the reason in:

1. A strategy executes only on bar close
2. A position opens (order fills) only on next bar after `strategy.entry/exit` was executed (condition met)

Comment: Is there any description of this in the pine documentation?

Comment: Here https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Strategies.html : `... By default, during both historical and real-time calculation, code is calculated on the bar’s close....` And `Broker Emulator` section has useful info too